# Как экранировать строку в Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Добрый день. На сайте подключён Angular и средствами PHP выводится некоторый блок текста. Проблема в том что в этом тексте могут встречать двойные фигурные скобки {{}} которые ангуляр пытается выполнить как своё выражение и вылетает с ошибкой синтаксиса. Можно ли как-то явно указать что эти блоки "нельзя трогать" ангуляру?

PHP:

```
<p><?= $question['content']; ?></p>
```

Выводит из базы: https://yadi.sk/i/SyAsB9Ojpn22q

Comment: добавьте пример разметки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable

```
<code ng-non-bindable>{{example}}</code>
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо